# ACRA: Getting error reports from other applications?

Tags: android, acra

I've been using ACRA for my app to get stack trace reports and its been working great but lately I have received two stack trace reports (from two different users it seems) which appear to have no tie to my application so I'm not sure if its a problem on my side (my app) or maybe ACRA?

Here's the stack trace

```
   STACK_TRACE = java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.qihoo.sandbox.monitor.SystemMonitor$SendBroadcastThread.SendRegisterBroadcast(SystemMonitor.java:41)
    at com.qihoo.sandbox.monitor.SystemMonitor$SendBroadcastThread.run(SystemMonitor.java:78)
```

The package name is not my app and my investigation has led to an application called Qihoo 360 which is a mobile security app.

my first thought is maybe this application blocked my app (a false positive) but when I installed Qihoo, then my app and some tests, I did not find any issues. Should I be concerned?

Other information: I can post my ACRA implementation if its needed but its the same as the tutorial provided in the documentation.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've started getting some of these crashes now too. It appears to com.qihoo pretends to be a security system but appears to be more like inept malware.

Comment: I'm getting the same crashes, the devices are always rooted. QIhoo 360 has an option to run in root mode, I'm guessing it injects itself into your process somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only 2 ways for this to occur.

1)  That crash occurred from within your app's VM. Perhaps because that security library has managed to inject itself into Android framework calls.

2)  Another app is sending reports to your crash server. It they are using the same key or URL as you.